# Kotlin Flow.collect executes but does not update ui onConfigurationChanged

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I'm using `Flow` to get data from Room then I call `Flow.collect` in my FragmentLogic class. Inside `collect{}` I do some work and update the View through an Interface( example: `view.updateAdapter(collectData)`). This works fine until an `onConfigurationChanged` is called and the screen rotates, the code inside collect executes and works in Logcat but anything that changes the UI does not work, the function `updateAdapter()` is called however nothing happens. One solution I found is to call the function `beginObservingProductList()` again in `onStart()` if savedinstance is not null but that creates two instances of the collect{} and they both show in logcat.

I want the UI changes to work even after `onConfigurationChanged` is called.

Room Dao class:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM product")
fun observableList(): Flow<List<ProductEntity>>
```

then in the implementation:

```
 productDao.observableList().map { collection ->
            collection.map { entity ->
                entity.toProduct
            }
 }.flowOn(DispatchThread.io())
```

And finally I collect the data and change the view:

```
 private fun beginObservingProductList() = this.launch {
    vModel.liveProductList.map {
        mapToSelectionProduct(it)
 }.collect {
        ui { view.updateAdapter(it) }
        if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
            filledListState()
     } else {
            emptyListState()
     }
        updateCosts()
        vModel.firstTime = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flow is not lifecycle aware, you should use [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.) to handle configuration changes.

To use LiveData with Flow,
implement `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0`, then you can use `.asLiveData()` extension func.

Repository

```
fun getList()= productDao.observableList().map { collection ->
        collection.map { entity ->
            entity.toProduct
        }
}.flowOn(DispatchThread.io())
```

ViewModel

```
val liveData = repository.getList().asLiveData()
```

Activity/Fragment

```
 viewModel.liveData.observe(this,Observer{ list->

//do your thing
})
```